# Website can't reached on PC but work fine in Mobiles

Tags: laravel, error-handling, laravel-5.6

I have a website `examrunner.com`. And my website opens sometimes but not always. Most of the time it says site can't reach server timed out. Can anyone tell me why my website not open always.

**website works fine in mobile always but not in pc**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEyTM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like DNS caching to me. you might have tried to visit the website on your router before the DNS had propagated, when you say it works on mobile my guess is that you are on a mobile network and not your router so the DNS will work fine.

Flush your dns by either setting it to a new network like googles `8.8.8.8` or restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cellular network from your smartphone it can be provider dns cache.
If you want to check website from your computer just change your hosts file

> **sudo nano /etc/hosts** for linux/mac
>
> **c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts** open and change in any editor for Windows

and put in the end of file

your.website.ip  yourdomain.com

After this action you'll be able to connect your website directly.